# $2a^2 – bc – 9a + 10 = 0$ then the range of $‘a’$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be real numbers such that $2a^2 – bc – 9a + 10 = 0 $ and $4b^2 + c^2 + bc – 7a – 8 = 0,$ then the range of $‘a’$ is?

How to do we proceed ? Should I make quadratic in $a$ ?

**Ans:** $a \in [1,4.2]$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @maveric, would you like to accept any of these answers? :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$(2b – c)^2 + 5bc – 7a – 8 = 0\quad...(i) \\
2a^2 – bc – 9a + 10 = 0\quad...(ii) $$ Now, $5(ii) + (i) = ? $.

Comment: Then have a quadratic in a.

Comment: @maveric, Yes, you got it!

Answer (score 2):

When using the quadratic formula you have the part under the square root, so a is real only if the value of the square root is real, so all you need to do (in the first equation) is to plug in the numbers under the square root and check when it is larger or equal to zero.
For the second equation, you need to to change it so you have $a =\dots$ and then check when the left side of the equation is real
And now you can take the intersection of the two ranges

Answer (score 1):

From the first equality

$bc=2a^2-9a+10$

$\Rightarrow (4b)c=8a^2-36a+40 \quad (1)$

Substituting in the $2$nd expression,

$4b^2+c^2-9a+2a^2+10-7a-8=0    $

$\Rightarrow 4b^2+c^2=-2a^2+16a+8 \quad (2)$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get

$(2b+c)^2=6a^2-20a+48=2(3a^2-10a+24)$

Note that $3a^2-10a+24\gt 0 ,\forall a$

Similarly on subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$, we get

$(2b-c)^2=-10a^2+52a-32=-2(5a^2-26a+16)$

Find the range of $a$ where $5a^2-26a+16 \le 0$

This range will give the answer

Comment: Your value of $bc$ is not correct to start with. Please check.

Comment: @MathLover  Right ,thank you. Let me edit it.